# Regex to replace single delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to find a limiter in a string " - ". The problem is that there may be other occurrences of "-" which makes the regex a bit more complex

```
a-b
a - b
a-b - c-d
-a-b- - -c-d-
```

should end up as

```
a - b
a - b
a b - c d
a b - c d
```

One " - " delimiter only.
Other hyphen characters to be replaced by spaces.

```
import re

def clean_delimter(s):
  regx = re.sub(r"(\s?-\s?)", " - ", s)
  print regx
  return regx

myList = [
"a-b",
"a - b",
"a-b - c-d",
"-a-b- - -c-d-"
]

for i in range(0, len(myList)):
  clean_delimter(myList[i])
```

My regex changes all hyphens which is not what I'm after. But I don't know how to tell Reg how to find

```
\s*-|\s*-\s*|-\s*
```

and then look for other occurrences of "-", changing them to " "

Comment: You should try using e.g. https://regex101.com/#python, http://pythex.org/

Comment: Firstly note that `x*` matches 0 occurrences of `x` so `\s*-|\s*-\s*|-\s*` can be simplified to just `\s*-\s*`

Comment: Secondly your example input and output make it very unclear what you're trying to accomplish in the general case. The first case `"a-b" -> "a - b"` is completely different from the others. Should the solution be taking a different path if `" - "` isn't present in the input? In that case a single regex isn't appropriate for you. The last case is also weird. If there are hyphens on the sides they should be deleted rather than replaced with spaces?

Comment: I was hoping for a magic bullet solution with regex. However I will probably have to sift through the strings and deal with odd cases as they happen. The second case where a single hyphen needs to be changed to "-". But if I do a global change for that it'll get messy methinks

Comment: You have multiple cases here really. You need to be more specific about what constitutes a delimiter, a hyphen to be replaced by a space, or a hyphen that is to be removed. Are they always symmetrical? Are hyphens outside of text always removed? Is the center hyphen always the delimiter? Answer those questions and you will significantly refine the case.

Answer (score 0):

since you data is symmetrical, it could be done without regex:

```
result = []
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.count('-') > 1:
            n = (line.count('-')  -1) // 2
            line = line.replace('-',' ', n)
            #reverse
            line = line[::-1]
            line = line.replace('-',' ', n)
            # reverse to the original order
            line = line[::-1]
            line = re.sub(r'\s+',r' ', line)
            result.append(line)
        else:
            result.append(line)

for line in result:
    print(line)

a-b
a - b
a b - c d
a b - c d
```